# Demonstration of the slope of a line, is equal to the tangent of the angle

Tags: geometry

He was showing the relationship between an angle and the length of its opposite side. And get to that, $tg \alpha = \frac{o}{a}$, where $o$ = opposite side, $a$ = adjacent side.

You can see this in the photo:

[image]

I did not know that I would get to the tangent, I just looked for a relationship between the angle $\alpha$ and long of the side $c$. So, my last problem was "how to convert the degrees $\alpha$ to the value of a slope", then I found that $ m = tan \alpha$.

I need a demostratiom how to get the slope of a line A, only with the angle formed by the axis X and the line A. and that's what the tangent does. But I want to know how it is possible that the "tan" operator converts an angle into the value of its slope, that is m=tanα –

Comment: Answer1: that's not something you prove, it's the definition of the tangent.
Answer2: if you disagree, then what *is* in your opinion the definition of the tangent?

Comment: Please make this edit to the question: point out the best explanation you found on the internet, and tell us why even that explanation is "superficial." Without knowing the criteria you're looking for in an explanation, it seems a waste of time to try to explain this.

Comment: I already edit the post

Answer (score 1):

Consider the right-angled triangle of the points $(0, 0)$, $(c, 0)$, and $(c, s)$, where $c=\cos(\alpha)$ and $s=\sin(\alpha)$. Then the 2-point form of the line provides

$$m:=\frac{y_1-y_2}{x_1-x_2}=\frac{s-0}{c-0}=\frac{\sin(\alpha)}{\cos(\alpha)}=:\tan(\alpha)$$

--- rk

Answer (score 0):

For a ratio of opposite over adjacent, a function was created (tangent) to correspond to the angle that was formed by this ratio.